# Mocking SimpleXML HTML Calls

Tags: mocking, phpunit, simplexml

I'm currently writing a package which involves loading details from an api. I'm writing the tests for it and I'm not entirely sure the best way of doing it. Since testing the api will involve making a request to a site, I want to avoid it (especially as the api in question isn't the fastest in the world) if I can.

What's the best way of testing that I'm loading the xml from a page and converting it into the objects that I want it to, without actually loading that page in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I finally solved it was a brainwave where I realised I was being an idiot

We can write a class that does the following:

```
class XMLReader {
  function parse($url) {
    return simplexml_load_file($url)
  }
}
```

We can then inject this class into the api class

```
class Api {
  protected xmlreader;
  public function __construct(XMLReader $xmlreader) {
    $this->xmlreader = $xmlreader;
  }

  public function apiCall($params) {
     $url = getUrlFromParams($params);
     $apiAnswer = $this->xmlreader->parse($url);
  }
}
```

And now we can just mock up an XMLReader class, and tell it to parse a local file instead of a file online.

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('XMLReader');
$mock->shouldReceive('parse')->with('http://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/13291?versions=1')->andReturn(simplexml_load_file('tests/13291.xml'))->once();
$api = new Api($mock);
$game = $api->getBoardGame($this->gameID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should test the XML processing and the network requests separately.

For testing the XML parsing, grab some example XMLs manually, save them on disk, and use them as fixtures. The parse classes should have the XML string as an input and should output the desired object. So in your tests, instead of calling the API for getting the XML you load it from disk and inject it to see if the generated object is the expected. This way you can even simulate bad XMLs or whatever you want.

For the requests, just test that you're doing the right calls to curl or whatever library you're using for consuming the API.

Then you can also write some integration tests, that will do the whole process, just to make sure that the process is correctly chained. But the trick is that these integration tests don't need to test all the XML types, just one or two.

Comment: But I don't actually need to test the network requests or the parsing if I'm using simplexml_load_file if I'm correct? I can be confident that simplexml_load_file will return a bunch of XML documents that I can work with. I'm not sure how to mock the call and get a SimpleXML object back.

Comment: As you comment, if the objects you are generating are SimpleXML objects, then you don't need to test their generation. Anyway, if you want not to use the network for consuming the API on your tests, you'll have to load the responses from disk for simulating the API calls.